# Match exactly query in Kibana demo

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am testing default demo of Kibana: `Dashboard [eCommerce] Revenue Dashboard`.
When I filter from `[eCommerce] Controls`, for example, setting the category to `Men's Accessories` I see other categories on `[eCommerce] Sales by Category`. How can I change that?

I see that the query is built like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "category.keyword": {
        "query": "Men's Accessories",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So this translates to:

```
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "category.keyword": {
              "query": "Men's Accessories"
            }
          }
        },
```

How can I change this demo to show exactly the category that I selected?

Example screen:
[image]

**EDIT:**

I'm not looking for some silly solution - that work one time.
I want to show only one category - but with one filter - not one filter and for example three negation. If i change my category to another - put it simply i chose "women's shoes" i want to show only that category from applying only this one filter that i chosed from the dashboard - not some custom made filter by typing some words. 
I want to make visualization that when applied shows `excatly` one category - not 4 like right now.

**EDIT:**
I created two documents (with brand new `Men's TEST_NEW_CATEGORY`)   in Kibana `Dev Tools` section with this:

```
POST kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_doc/
{
    "category": [
      "Men's TEST_NEW_CATEGORY"
    ],
    "currency": "EUR",
    "customer_first_name": "Youssef",
    "customer_full_name": "Youssef Jensen",
    "customer_gender": "MALE",
    "customer_id": 31,
    "customer_last_name": "Jensen",
    "customer_phone": "",
    "day_of_week": "Saturday",
    "day_of_week_i": 5,
    "email": "youssef@jensen-family.zzz",
    "manufacturer": [
      "Low Tide Media"
    ],
    "order_date": "2019-05-15T23:45:36+00:00",
    "order_id": 592109,
    "products": [
      {
        "base_price": 49.99,
        "discount_percentage": 0,
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturer": "Low Tide Media",
        "tax_amount": 0,
        "product_id": 12202,
        "category": "Men's TEST_NEW_CATEGORY",
        "sku": "ZO0396603966",
        "taxless_price": 49.99,
        "unit_discount_amount": 0,
        "min_price": 26.49,
        "_id": "sold_product_592109_12202",
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "created_on": "2016-12-31T23:45:36+00:00",
        "product_name": "Moccasins - stone",
        "price": 49.99,
        "taxful_price": 49.99,
        "base_unit_price": 49.99
      },
      {
        "base_price": 28.99,
        "discount_percentage": 0,
        "quantity": 1,
        "manufacturer": "Low Tide Media",
        "tax_amount": 0,
        "product_id": 15017,
        "category": "Men's Clothing",
        "sku": "ZO0452704527",
        "taxless_price": 28.99,
        "unit_discount_amount": 0,
        "min_price": 13.63,
        "_id": "sold_product_592109_15017",
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "created_on": "2016-12-31T23:45:36+00:00",
        "product_name": "Jumper - off-white",
        "price": 28.99,
        "taxful_price": 28.99,
        "base_unit_price": 28.99
      }
    ],
    "sku": [
      "ZO0396603966",
      "ZO0452704527"
    ],
    "taxful_total_price": 78.98,
    "taxless_total_price": 78.98,
    "total_quantity": 2,
    "total_unique_products": 2,
    "type": "order",
    "user": "youssef",
    "geoip": {
      "country_iso_code": "US",
      "location": {
        "lon": -74,
        "lat": 40.8
      },
      "region_name": "New York",
      "continent_name": "North America",
      "city_name": "New York"
    }
}
```

Then i clearly see that there is only one category when using standard filter button:

[image]

Comment: What other categories do you see?

Comment: @Archer I've added example screen. I wanted to see only `Men's Accessories` not `Men's Clothing` for example (Diagram in bottom right corner).

Comment: I forgot to press `apply` - I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter by a specific category, you would want to use `filter` instead of `terms`. Terms aggregation will be applied on all the values in the field. Also, notice that i disabled terms aggregation using toggle. I'm using **only** filter for the use case you mentioned

You can set it up like below:
[image: Filter by One Category]

You can also add multiple filters like below:

[image: multiple filters]

Another option is add a `scripted field` and visualize on those scripted fields, but this case is pretty straight forward i.e. from one field so that is not required. However, when collating data from several fields - scripted fields can be useful.

**Updated Answer :**

The demo is restrictive, you cannot change the data or play around with analyzers. But in reality you can filter out an array by exact match for a value you want and then apply the filter.

For now, if you filter the array using dev tools in kibana you will see it returns all documents where it matches your category - it may or may not have extra categories but it will always have what you are looking for.

hence, when you add a filter you still see other categories in visualization since thats how the data is.

[image: kibana query]

Comment: I would like to have button like before and select category from it dynamically. I see that you are making static visualization - could you edit your answer to make it dynamic like the one in the question?

Comment: Well technically the filter that you add at the top is the way to make it work. But in this case, it will not work like you are expecting since the orders have `multiple categories`. Scroll down to last visualization and you can see the document itself contains two categories and it matches the one you filter from: https://prnt.sc/noyig4. This is data related.

Comment: @tryingHard I updated my answer and added some more details

Comment: Thanks - i edited the question - I've added new index with brand new category (that appears only solo) - and you are certainly right - that is was casued by the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.  I had to use 4 filters only to see Men's Clothing.

[image]

The image might be too small to recognize, so I will write them down.

**The first filter :**

```
{
"query": {
  "match": {
    "category.keyword": {
       "query": "Men's Clothing",
        "type": "phrase"
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

**The second filter:**

```
{
   "query": {
     "match": {
       "category.keyword": {
          "query": "Women's Accessories",
          "type": "phrase"
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

**The third filter:**

```
{
    "query": {
       "match": {
          "category.keyword": {
             "query": "Men's Shoes",
             "type": "phrase"
             }
           }
         }
       }
```

**The fourth filter:**

```
{
   "query": {
     "match": {
     "category.keyword": {
        "query": "Men's Accessories",
         "type": "phrase"
       }
      }
    }
  }
```

**I don't know why but if I view the query as DSL it doesn't show "is not" operator.** so let me show you an image of "is not" operator.

[image]

Then, you will see all the dashboard only with one category like below.

[image]

Now I just realized you only wanted to see  men's accessory not men's clothing.  My poor eyesight.  However,  I hope you got a rough idea. If you want, I can do men's clothing. Let me know.  Btw, I tried to do it with just one filter but somehow the graph wouldn't work.

Comment: This is not a solution. I want to show only one - but with one filter - not one filter and three negation. If i change my category to anotther - put it simply i chose "women's shoes" i want to show only that category from applying only this one filter that i chosed `from the dashboard` - not some custom made filter by typing some words. I want to make `visualization` that when applied shows `excatly` one category.

Comment: "Btw, I tried to do it with just one filter but somehow the graph wouldn't work."
The main issue is here that you need to make query excatly by default from dashboard - maybe not as a phrase.